# `Build Error` Error -1073741819 - C

Tags: c, file-io, struct, linked-list

my assignment is to take in a data file of all the possible letters for each die from the game Boggle. Here's a copy of the data file:

```
   D R L X E I
   C P O H S A
   N H N L Z R
   W T O O T A
   I O S S E T 
   N W E G H E
   B O O J A B
   U I E N E S
   P S A F K F
   I U N H M Qu
   Y R D V E L
   V E H W H R
   I O T M U C
   T Y E L T R
   S T I T Y D
   A G A E E N
```

Each die takes 6 of the letters, and these are stored in a linked list. When I have tried to run the following code, I keep getting an error code: `C:\Dev-Cpp\Makefile.win [Build Error]  [Untitled1.o] Error -1073741819`

I've tried using 3 different IDEs, but always seem to get some compiling issue. I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong! This isn't complete yet by any means but would rather figure this out before I keep going deeper and deeper. Thanks in advance!

*code*:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define LENGTH 80

struct boggleDataNode{
       char data[3];
       struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
}*head;

struct boggleDieSideNode{
       char dieSideData[3];
       struct boggleDieSideNode *nextSide;
}*head1;

void readData(struct boggleDataNode temp);

int main(){
    int counter = 0;
    struct boggleDataNode *head;
    struct boggleDieSideNode *head1;
    struct boggleDataNode *temp;
    *head = NULL;
    *head1 = NULL;
    *temp = *head;
    readData(*temp);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void readData(struct boggleDataNode temp){
    //initializing variables including
    //opening the input file
    FILE *input = fopen("BoggleData.txt","r");
    int name =0; 
    int id=0;
    char data[96] ={};

    //error checking that the file opened
    if (input == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while( fscanf(input, "%s", &data) != EOF)
           printf("%s", data);

}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: That sounds like a runtime error, not a build error.  Not that you're wrong...

Comment: `*head = NULL;`  : *(NULL) = NULL. and  type mis-match.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: *Now* you're talkin'

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I actually just added the `*head = NULL` before I copied this code here... Figured I needed to intialize it

Comment: you want `struct boggleDataNode *head = NULL;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY just tried that and it is still giving me the same issue.

Comment: `head1` and `temp` ditto. and delete `*head = NULL;
    *head1 = NULL;
    *temp = *head;`

Comment: also change Interface of `void readData(struct boggleDataNode temp)`

Comment: `char data[96] ={};` --> `char data[96] ={0};`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY tried those fixes but seem to be getting a `Source file not compiled` issue when trying to run after compiling. Using DevC++ and Windows 8

Comment: Please write the error message if you are still obtained a build error.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think I seemed to have "fixed it" by switching to Code::Blocks and taking away the `readData` function. Must lie somewhere in my passing `temp` to the function...

Comment: `char boggleDiceData[16][6][3];`...`void readData(char data[16][6][3])`

Comment: there are several problems with the code,  starting with '*head' is defined in the global file space and again in the main() function.

Comment: this line: '*temp = *head;' is saying to assign the value found at *head (which happens to be the value at address 0 since head contains NULL) to the location where *temp is pointed,  However temp is not pointed to any place in particular.   Perhaps you meant:  temp = head;  which would assign NULL to temp

Comment: suggest the struct be modified to hold 1 row of data rather than 3 characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, change

```
struct boggleDataNode{
       char data[3];
       struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
}*head;
```

to

```
struct boggleDataNode{
       char data[3];
       struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
};
```

as it seems you don't need a global pointer for that structure anyway. As per your usage, it will be *shadowed* by the local `head`.

Same goes for `head1` also.

Next, you assign `NULL` to a pointer itself, not to the variable it *points to*. (FWIW, `NULL` itself is a pointer, an *invalid* one, though).

Change

```
*head = NULL;
```

to

```
head = NULL;
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the answer! I tried both of those and now am getting `Error 255` which seems to be related to a "makefile"?

Comment: it seems to have gone away after I copied + pasted into a brand new file, but now am getting an issue saying `Source file not compiled` when trying to compile & run in DevC++

Comment: @bravesaint i personally never used DevC++, but you can try 1) deleting previous executable, if present 2)compile using the command line. Tht's all I can say. sorry.

Comment: thank you, friend! I will keep trying to find out what is causing this! Can you recommend a different IDE? I've been having issues with Code::Blocks and Visual Studio as well.

Comment: @bravesaint You're welcome. I don't use an IDE, so can't recommend. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Whatever else in your program logic is wrong, there's also a syntax error in

```
 char data[96] ={};
```

since ISO C forbids empty array initializers. If your build breaks due to this, it may explain the "Build Error". If you want data to be zero initialized, a single `= { 0 }` will do.

It is also a good idea to crank up the warning level of your compiler by adding appropriate options. What system (OS) is this? Which compiler?

Comment: I'm using DevC++ on Windows 8. Just made that change, didn't seem to fix much.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the ampersand from "&data" because i believe you're trying to read a string, so pass the string, not the direccion.

```
 while( fscanf(input, "%s", &data) != EOF)
       printf("%s", data);
```

so you'd have this:

```
  while( fscanf(input, "%s", data) != EOF)
       printf("%s", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

strongly suggest, when compiling to enable all warnings, then fix those warnings.   Afterall, the compiler knows the language much better than us humans.

The following code

1) compiles cleanly,

2) has unneeded items either commented out or #if 0...#endif out

3) checks for input errors

4) uses 'perror()' to properly output system function error info
   including the message related to the current 'errno' value

5) closes the input file after all reading completed

6) the fscanf() will stop after reading one numeric char from the input file
   because %s will stop when any 'white space' is encountered.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


//#define LENGTH 80
// Note: surround numeric #defines with parens to avoid text substituion errors
#define MAX_DATA_LEN (96)

#if 0
struct boggleDataNode
{
       char data[3];
       struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
};
#endif

#if 0
struct boggleDieSideNode
{
       char dieSideData[3];
       struct boggleDieSideNode *nextSide;
};
#endif


void readData( void );

int main( void )
{
    //int counter = 0;
    //struct boggleDataNode *head = NULL;
    //struct boggleDieSideNode *head1 = NULL;
    //struct boggleDataNode *temp = NULL;

    readData();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
} // end function: main


void readData()
{
    //initializing variables including
    //opening the input file
    //int name =0;
    //int id=0;
    char data[ MAX_DATA_LEN ];

    FILE *input = fopen("BoggleData.txt","r");
    //error checking that the file opened
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        perror("Can't open input file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( 1 == fscanf(input, " %s", data)) // note: format string leading space to skip 'white space'
           printf("%s", data);

    fclose( input );
} // end function: readData
```