# fscanf not reading in file

Tags: c, list, file, hyperlink, scanf

I am trying to read in a file and it tells me it cant find the file. I built i have a built in checker that looks to see if the file is there. I have the data file in my debug folder. Am I reading the file incorrectly? I am also using codeblocks for the IDE.

Here is my function calling my file:

```
char fileData[3];
    int bound = 96;
    //file pointer and file info
     FILE *ips;
     ips = fopen("data.txt", "r");
      if (ips == NULL)
        printf("Please check file!\n"); //this is the output I get
     else {
            //for loop to scan through file, and retrive the letters
            int i;
            for(i=0; i<bound; i++)
              fscanf(ips, "%c", &fileData);
              addBoggleData(head1, fileData);
              }
     //closes the file system
              close(ips);
}
```

Comment: What directory are you running the program from? That's where it will look for `data.txt`.

Comment: When you run this are you seing "Please check file!" and want to know why, or are you getting an error some place?

Comment: are you sure you have permission to do the reading?

Comment: You can't say that it's not reading, your program doesn't check that.

Comment: BTW `fscanf(ips, "%c", &fileData);` --> `fscanf(ips, "%2s", fileData);`

Comment: I am just getting the Please Check File.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY maybe the OP want's the raw data, not a string.

Comment: @iharob Perhaps it seems to be a situation similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31013245/971127). note that `Qu`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, either it's the same person, or they are sharing the code.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<bound; i++)` needs `{ }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cant scan file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085062/cant-scan-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

you stated the file failed to open.

Since the fopen() file name parameter has no path info.
and you stated the file is in the debug directory.

1) the execution and the file must be in the same directory

2) in this case, both the executable and the data file must be in the debug directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong parameter to `fscanf()`, you should pass the address of the `i`th element, like this

```
fscanf(ips, "%c", &fileData[i]);
```

and to be able to tell whether the data was read succesfully, you must check the return value of `fscanf()`, like

```
if (fscanf(ips, "%c", &fileData[i]) != 1)
 {
    warningReadingFailure();
 }
```

Also, the `fileData` array is way too small, you need to make it at least as big, as the number of bytes you intend to read from the file, i.e.

```
int bound = 96;
char fileData[bound];
```

Comment: You mean `if (fscanf(ips, "%c", &fileData[i]) == 1) printf("%c", fileData[i]);` and then the `printf()` didn't print anything? or did you try `printf("%s\n", fileData);`? Because that would be wrong.

Comment: the bound is for the amount of characters I am inputting. I have 96 letters i am trying to read in, and I pass each letter to a function to send into a link list individually.

Comment: Then you need `for (i = 0 ; i < bound ; i++) {char byte; if (fscanf(ips, "%c", &byte) != 1) continue; addBoggleData(head1, byte);}`!