# Cant scan file in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I am cant seem to get my simple script to read the file. All i am trying to do is read letters into an array. I just get random characters and it is driving me crazy. I have the file in the Debug folder, what else can go wrong? I am 100 percent sure everything is correct.

Here is my code:

```
FILE * ifp;
   ifp = fopen("letters.txt", "r");


   int i;
   int bound = 20;
   char data[20];


    for(i =0; i<bound; i++){
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", &data[1]);
        if (ifp == NULL){
            return;
        }
        printf("Data %d = %c\n", i, data[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Your code to input fix array of element like this &data[1]

Comment: Firstly, if you are trying to "read *letters*", why are you using `%s` specifier, which reads *strings* (words)? Secondly, why do you repeatedly read into the fixed `&data[1]` position? Thirdly, why are you repeatedly checking `ifp` for null, when there's no code that can possibly change `ifp` in the cycle?

Comment: ok I changed it to data[i] and it still does the same thing haha ugh! also changed the char type to "c" and that was to see if it read the file...which it isnt haha

Comment: always check (!=NULL) the returned value from fopen() to assure the operation was successful     Always check the returned value (not the parameter value) from fscanf() to assure the operation was successful.   fscanf(), when successful, when using %s will always use two locations in the input buffer as a NUL byte is always appended and using %s, if the letters are consecutive, will read them all on the first call to fscanf()  The input buffer is limited to 20 characters so the max allowed is 19 characters.  Add a length modifier to the %s of 19

Comment: ok i increase my array size, checked the null and got my error message. what can affect this program to not read a file?

Answer (score 2):

The following code

```
1) checks for errors
2) compiles cleanly
3) works on a test.txt file I produced.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define bound (20)

int main( void )
{
    FILE * ifp;

    if( NULL == (ifp = fopen("letters.txt", "r") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for letters.txt failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful


    int i;

    char data[bound];


    for(i =0; i<bound; i++)
    {
        if( 1 != fscanf(ifp, "%c", &data[i]) )
        { // then fscanf failed
            perror( "fscanf failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fscanf successful

        printf("Data %d = %c\n", i, data[i]);
    }
    return(0);
} // end function: main
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm could it be because

```
 &data[1]
```

should be just

```
data
```

or the equivalent

```
&data[0]
```

which is likely what you intended.

?

Only other reason I can think of is, the line you are reading is greater than 20 characters and its overflowing the data array.

Have a look at this example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LINES 10
#define MAX_LINE  80
#define FILE_NAME "lines.txt"

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char lines[MAX_LINES][MAX_LINE];
  FILE *fp;
  int i = 0;

  if (!(fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r"))) {
    perror ("file open error");
    return 1;
  }

  while (i < MAX_LINES) {
    if (fgets (lines[i], MAX_LINE, fp)) {
      printf ("Line[%d]=%s", i, lines[i]);
      i++;
    } else {
      printf ("End of file: closing %s\n", FILE_NAME);
      break;
    }
  }
  fclose (fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ gcc -o x1 -Wall -pedantic -g x1.c
$ ./x1
Line[0]=Come and listen to my story
Line[1]='Bout a man named Jed
Line[2]=Poor mountaineer,barely kept his fam'ly fed
End of file: closing lines.txt
```

Note:

1. We're reading a line at a time
2. We're reading each line into an array
3. We define the #/elements in the array (MAX_LINES) and the maximum size of each string (MAX_LINE) ahead of time
4. We check for "file open error" (and return "non-zero" accordingly)
5. We use "fgets()" to safely read a line (without risking a buffer overrun).

If you wanted to read a character at a time, the program could be as simple as:

```
 char string[MAX_LINE], *c;
 ...
 if (!(fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r"))) {
    perror ("file open error");
    return 1;
 }
 ...     
 c = string;
 while ((*c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF)
    c++;
```

One problem with the second example is that it doesn't check for string length >> MAX_LINE.  But hopefully it helps give you some ideas...